# Why chromium does not ask for admin password to visualize stored passwords?

Tags: password, chromium, keyrings

So it's been a while I am puzzled with this question. A few years ago when I wanted to see passwords stored by chromium I had to enter my computer admin password but now (different computer, different ubuntu version) it's not the case. Concretely anyone accessing my computer and opening chromium can browse and snoop at all my passwords.

I checked my ~/.local/share/keyrings directory and it gaves me the following

```
my@comp:~/.local/share/keyrings$ ls -al
total 1336
drwx------ 1 jb jb    134 nov.  17 20:38 .
drwx------ 1 jb jb   1022 nov.  18 10:32 ..
-rw------- 1 jb jb 754439 nov.  17 20:38 login.keyring
-rw------- 1 jb jb 300628 janv.  5  2018 login.keyring.temp-1715131298
-rw------- 1 jb jb 300628 janv.  5  2018 .temp-IARUBZ
-rw------- 1 jb jb    207 mai    5  2017 user.keystore
```

I tried a couple of google searches but people are more focused on how to stop chrome asking for a password on their Windows computer (quite the exact opposite, Windows' users seem to be less sensitive to security issues... ^^,)

Thanks a lot in advance for you help ! :-)[image: Clicking on the eye icon directly show the password] (About the above picture: clicking on the eye icon directly shows the password in chromium settings)

Comment: " Concretely anyone accessing my computer and opening chromium can browse and snoop at all my passwords. "  That only happens if you enter a keyring with an empty password. Adding a password to it would have it ask it again. What -might- have changed: it could be we now accept access too if the password keyring = your sudo password. Not sure so no answer; just a comment to get you going :)